# Verify the target Query Group in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I created a query group **test** through console and Executed the following query which worked fine.

> set query_group to 'test';
>
> INSERT INTO dummy (timestamp,productid) VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-25 23:14:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'DummyProduct');
>
> reset query_group

And it worked as expected.

Then I ran the same queries but with a query group that did not exist (eg: XYZ)
and even that query worked fine.

1. How did the second query got executed as there was no query group to which it could go. Is it like if query group doesn't exist, request goes to default queue ?
2. How can we verify which query went to which query group ?

Answer (score 0):

The [STL_QUERY table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) contains a field called **label**:

> Either the name of the file used to run the query or a label defined with a `SET QUERY_GROUP` command. If the query is not file-based or the `QUERY_GROUP` parameter is not set, this field value is default.

Comment: Yeah I have already checked this table. In that I could see we have a label XYZ. As far as my understanding, we have query group test, and label test, then the query will go to this query group. But in my case the query group is not at all defined. So if label is there i.e. QUERY_GROUP parameter is set but that query group itself doesn't exist, then where will the query execute.